# get the image path stored in isolated storage of windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am saving a image in isolated storage of windows phone 8. It is saving correctly. But when I am trying to access it, it is not working.

I need to change an image in live tile of windows phone 8 on run time. So I am saving the images in isolated storage first, then trying to set that image in live tile. But it is not showing on live tile. Only change title is coming on tile. Here is the code that I am using for setting saved image in live tile...

```
            FlipTileData tileData = new FlipTileData 
            {
                Title = "Conference Calls",
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/backImage.png", UriKind.Absolute),
            };

            ShellTile mainTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

            if (mainTile != null)
            {
                mainTile.Update(tileData);
            }
```

Comment: are you using this path to save the image `"isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/backImage.png"`?

Comment: yes i am using this path, I checked in isolated storage, I got the image there.